# How do I create a finite state automata for addition in ternary system?

Tags: finite-automata

I've been scratching my head with this one for a few hours now, but am feeling to stupid to comprehend how it is to be done. I can't understand the way even the state table should be built for this one. From where should I start?

Comment: finite state automatons don't have an output. Also, its memory is finite so it could never implement addition

Comment: @nirshahar Actually, [transducers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer) are finite state automata that have an output.

Comment: Binary addition can be checked using a finite state automaton if we code the operation in triple bits: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/129213/4287

Comment: This is a good question, but can you provide more details on the precise question? The issue here is, depending on how ternary addition is encoded, it may or may not be representable using finite automata.

Comment: @6005 , that's pretty muсh the way the task has been posited to me. no restrictions on the encoding. i seem to grasp it only superficially, unfortunately. what encoding way can be representable through finite automata?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it is to begin with an addition in binary. Since you didn't give any indication on the formatting of the input, I will make my own choices here.

Suppose the input alphabet is $\Sigma = \{0,1\}^2 = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1, 0), (1,1)\}$. An input is of the form $(a_0,b_0)(a_1,b_1)…(a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$, meaning we want to add $x = (a_0a_1…a_{n-1})_2$ and $y = (b_0b_1…b_{n-1})_2$, where $(…)_2$ represents the reverse binary encoding (meaning $x = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i2^i$, for example $13 = (1011)_2$).

I will create a [Mealy Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine) computing $x+y\mod 2^n$. The idea is to use two states, depending on the need of a carry or not.

[image]

Here, a transition $a|\alpha$ means that when reading $a$, I write $\alpha$ on the output.

$q_0$ represents the state without carry, and $q_1$ represents the state with a carry. A carry appears from $q_0$ when adding two $1$ bits. If that's the case, the state will become $q_1$. The carry will disappear only when adding two $0$ bits.

Now what you need to do is getting inspired by this machine and try to do the same in ternary, with input alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1,2\}^2$.

Comment: sorry if this is the stupidest question you've ever heard but i'm trying my best to understand it despite my horrible bandwidth... there should remain 2 states?

Comment: In your opinion, what could be the carry when adding in ternary?

Comment: 0,1,2? There should be 27 tuple values for the ternary system then? @Nathaniel