# DFA for $a+b=c$, where $a,b,c$ are input in parallel

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I've faced this question in my homework, it's a bonus question so it's harder than I could do now with my current knowledge, so if anyone could help I'll be thankful.

We're given $\Sigma=\{0,1\}^3$. We think of the 'letters' of the language as column vectors, so every $w\in\Sigma ^*$ is a matrix $M_w$ that consists of $3$ rows and $n$ columns. We refer to the binary numbers represented by $M_w$ rows by $a_w,b_w,c_w$. For example: if $w=(0,1,1)(1,0,1)$ so:
$$
M_w = \begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&&a_w&=01 \\
1&0&\Longrightarrow&b_w&=10 \\
1&1&&c_w&=11
\end{array}
$$

We define the language $L=\{w\in \Sigma ^* \mid a_w+b_w=c_w\}$. For example, the $w$ above is  related to $L$. However, $w'=(0,1,1)(1,0,1)(1,0,0)$ is not since $a_w=011, b_w=100, c_w=110$.

**Question:** Describe DFA (Deterministic Finite Automata) that accepts $L$.

Comment: It is a bonus question. It tests your knowledge, not ours!

Comment: A hint might be in the answer [How do I create a finite state automata for addition in ternary system?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/145727/4287).

Comment: Try first the easier question in which the numbers are encoded LSB to MSB (this corresponds to reversing the order of bits in $a_w,b_w,c_w$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define function $d:\Sigma^*\to \mathbb Z$, $d(w)=a_w+b_w-c_w$. So $w\in L\iff d(w)=0$.

Let us see how $d(w)$ changes if $w$ is extended by a letter $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\in\Sigma$.

Let $w'=w\sigma$. By the definition of a binary number, we have
\begin{aligned}
a_{w'} &= 2\times a_{w} + a\\  
b_{w'} &= 2\times b_{w} + b\\ 
c_{w'} &= 2\times c_{w} + c\\ 
\end{aligned}
So,
$$d(w') = 2\times d(w) + d(\sigma)$$
Note that $-1\le d(\sigma)\le 2$.

- $d(w)\le -2 \implies d(w')\le -2$
- $d(w)=-1 \implies d(w')=-2 + d(\sigma)$
- $d(w)=0 \implies d(w')=d(\sigma)$
- $d(w)\ge 1 \implies d(w')\ge 1$

Let us construct a DFA with three states $q_{\le-2\,\text{or}\,\ge1}$, $q_{=-1}$, and $q_{=0}$.

- $q_{\le-2\,\text{or}\,\ge1}$ for $w$ such that $d(w)\le-2$ or $d(w)\ge1$.
- $q_{=-1}$ for $w$ such that $d(w)=-1$.
- $q_{=0}$ for $w$ such that $d(w)=0$.

Readers can specify the accept state and the transition function so that the DFA accepts $L$.

---

Here is a nice DFA provided by OP.

> [image: a DFA drawn by OP]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check the answer later, I will inform you if there's anything that I think needed to be updated or clarified, it may take me a few days to check since I'm busy lately.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $\delta$, I know that $\delta$ gets two parameters, state and $\sigma \in \Sigma$, and it returns a state too. Formally, $\delta (q\in Q, \sigma \in \Sigma )=q'\in Q$. If you can please explain how you've defined $\delta$ like this. Thanks.

Comment: If you can give a full answer please I will be thankful. What I mean if you can define the DFA formally, I really get the idea but it's still somehow hard to define it properly for me. Thanks again.

Comment: First of all thanks. Also, if you like I have drawn https://ibb.co/s6bMjNC which I think is more elegant, so if you would like you can add it to your answer.

Comment: @CSStudent Done.